# Convert OpenType font to TrueType with tabular number spacing

Tags: typography, opentype

Is there a way to convert an OpenType font to TrueType using tabular number spacing instead of the default/proportional.

The online converters I have found do not have these options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a font monospaced?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10644/how-can-i-make-a-font-monospaced) - there are a couple of answers in the duplicate question which might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find a tool to do this automatically, most likely. If your software does not allow you to choose tabular figures (which I imagine is the case), you would need to open the font in a font editor, change the tabular numbers for the regular ones (by copying and pasting into the right glyph slots), and re-export. You could use [FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/), which is open source for this.

But **before you do this** , make sure the licence for the fonts allows you to make modifications such as these.

Answer (score 1):

The Fontsquirrel Generator can turn OpenType features into default characters:
https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator